# unable to install django debug toolkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, debugging

Im new to django and trying to learn the basics, but when i try to install django debug tool kit in a virtual environment the installations keeps on failing and i get an error. is it because i need a specific version of django? im not sure and would appreciate any help.

in the terminal i used `pipenv install django-debug-toolkit` and get this:

`Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.`

`Installing django-debug-toolkit...`

`Resolving django-debug-toolkit...`

`Installing...`

`[   =] Installing django-debug-toolkit...[31m[1mError: [0m An error occurred while installing [32mdjango-debug-toolkit[0m!`

`Error text:`

`[36mERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-debug-toolkit (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-debug-toolkit`

`[0m`

`Installation Failed`

Comment: I think django-debug-toolkit does not exist but django-debug-toolbar does. Is that the one you are looking for?

Comment: OMG i spent hours looking for a solution just for it to be a typo. Thanks for the help :)